# Show nearby results first or search screen in search application

Tags: navigation, search

We are building a search app for finding nearby openings.

I am currently debating on my choice of showing a map of nearby openings to give the user immediate value as soon as possible.

The others want to show a search screen first.

I believe by making an assumption and delivering relevant data first this will be better for most users and when people want to search there is a button.

Any ideas or references to this train of thought?

Comment: You should create 2 samples and test on real user with real environment and pick the best solution. Don't assume.

Answer (score 1):

To provide results according to location, the user should give you access to it, otherwise, you are violating his privacy. So assuming that premise, the first thing that would happen on your app, if you go for the automatic option, wouldn't be showing results, but asking for permission to get the location.

Of course, we can assume that the user is using the app voluntarily and that he knows the conditions, risks, etc.

Offering results immediately sounds good from the perspective of the feeling or perception of dynamism of the app, not to mention that it may be what the user wants. But, what if the user is sitting on a coffee shop, close to a friends house looking for openings? Or in a train? Or in a bus?, Or checking the openings from another city to decide if he wants to move there? Or ... The first useful screen, apart of requesting the access to location would be useless, or slow due to circumstances that could be solved by giving him the chance to ask for what he wants.

Considering the last paragraph, offering a search option sounds much better because the user will have control over his privacy, can use the app without disclosing information and can decide quickly where to look for openings.

But there is an even better option; if you offer an introductory screen with both options, search or nearby openings, you are accomplishing both desires, yours and your partner's, not to mention that the user would have a much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the search option is no more than one click away, providing the user with a map of nearby openings is more valuable.

Even in the case where the user is not actually looking for nearby openings, the map will give them an idea of what type of results to expect, and for first time users or users who are exploring the app rather than very intentionally searching for something specific, the map will pull the user into the app and get them engaged. In most cases, a map of nearby openings will be more visually interesting than a blank search screen as well.